# Convert Datetime in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have Stored Procedure on SQL to get the time the database last updated. When O run the Query by itself, I get Month dd yyyy hh:mm AM/PM.

But when O execute stored procedure, I get yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

I need the Month dd yyyy hh:mm AM/Pm ( Apr 1 2022 7:30AM) format.
What Am I doing wrong in converting the datetime.

```sql
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetDBLastUpdatedTime]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @LastUpdatedTime Datetime OUTPUT  
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
        SET @LastUpdatedTime =(SELECT 
        convert(Varchar(MAX),last_user_update,100) as LastUpdatedTime
        FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
        WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'Emp')
        AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('tblEmployee'))
  RETURN;
END
```

Comment: You are assigning the output to a `datetime` output parameter. That will undo any string formatting shenanigans, so there's no point using convert here anyway (unless you change the output type to string, but that is not the right answer). Do that formatting at the presentation layer (also you don't need `MAX` for date strings - in this case `varchar(19)` is sufficient).

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format. Get rid of the `CONVERT` in your procedure, and then when your **application** consumes (and displays?) the value of the `OUTPUT` parameter format it *then*.

Comment: Why do you need it in a specific format ? For display on the screen ? That should be done by the presentation layer, in the database there is no format

Comment: On a related note, `varchar(MAX)` is an odd choice of a data type to convert a date and time value to. Style `100` will always return a 19 character length value; what do you need the other 7982+ characters for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real Datetime values **DO NOT HAVE A STRING FORMAT AT ALL**. What you see is a convenience shown you by the tool or environment where you ran the query. The actual value is a *binary format*. It's not really human-readable at all, but rather is more efficient for storage, transport, indexing, and operations like comparing or adding arbitrary days, months, milliseconds, etc.

If you need a specific format, *still return a raw (unformatted) DateTime value* from your database query, and then use the string conversion tools on whatever platform or reporting tool you're working with to get the desired format there, in the presentation level where it belongs.